# When I run my test suites they fail with PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm writing tests for my Play application and I want to run them with a real server so that I can fake all the answers from the external services.

In order to do that I extend PlaySpec and GuiceOneServerPerSuite and I override the method fakeApplication to create my routes and give them to the Guice Application

```
class MySpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneServerPerSuite {

  override def fakeApplication(): Application =
    GuiceApplicationBuilder().appRoutes(app => {
        case ("POST", "/url/") => app.injector.instanceOf(classOf[DefaultActionBuilder]) { Ok }
      }).globalApp(true).build()


  "Something" should {
    "work well" in {
      val wsClient = app.injector.instanceOf[WSClient]
      val service = new MyService(wsClient)
      service.method() mustBe ""

      app.injector.instanceOf[DBApi].databases().foreach(_.getConnection().close())
    }
  }
}
```

I have multiple test suites like this one and if I run them alone they work fine, but if I run them all together they fill up the connection pool and then everything fails with: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already.

My considerations: I think it happens because at each test suite a new Play Guice Application is created. I also tried to close the connections of all databases manually but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same problems, so we are separating these 2 use cases (running all or just one Test-Suite).

This makes running all tests much faster - as Play Environment is only started once.

The Suite looks like:

```
class AcceptanceSpecSuite
  extends PlaySpec
    with GuiceOneAppPerSuite
    with BeforeAndAfter {

  // all specs
  override def nestedSuites: immutable.IndexedSeq[AcceptanceSpec] = Vector(
    // api
    new DatabaseTaskSpec,
    new HistoryPurgeTaskSpec,
  ...
  )


  override def fakeApplication(): Application =
    // your initialization
}
```

Now each Spec looks like:

```
@DoNotDiscover // important that it is run only if called explicitly
class DatabaseTaskSpec extends AcceptanceSpec {
...
```

The Parent class now we can switch between `GuiceOneServerPerSuite` and `ConfiguredApp`:

```
trait AcceptanceSpec
  extends PlaySpec
     you need:
    // with GuiceOneServerPerSuite // if you want to test only one Test
    with ConfiguredApp // if you want to test all
    with Logging
    with ScalaFutures
    with BeforeAndAfter {
...
```

I know it's a bit of a hack - so I am also interested in a more elegant solution;).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for sharing your code! I tried the solution, and it works fine but in my case I also want to have different Routes for each test

Answer (score 1):

You can put your DB instance as a singleton, if you do that, he won´t create multiple instance, therefore won´t fill the connection pool.

Something like that:

```
@Singleton
object TestDBProperties extends DBProperties {
  override val db: Database = Database.forURL(
    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;",
    driver = "org.h2.Driver")
}
```

Hope this helps.